# How can I solve the error when I try to inherit a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I try to inherit a table in PostgreSQL. But, I get an error which i can't resolve.
I want to inherit table "Ronde" as a child of table "Spel".

The error message is:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 2: INHERIT public.%22Spel%22;
^
```

After that I tried to solve the problem using the description stated in:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-inheritance.html

So I tried to solve the problem using sql but I get the same error.

This is how the sql of "Spel" is now:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Spel" (

    "Id" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Spel_Id_seq"'::regclass),
    "AantalSpelers" integer,
    "Speler1Id" integer,
    "Speler2Id" integer,
    "Taal" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "AantalLetters" integer,
    CONSTRAINT "Spel_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Spel"
    OWNER to postgres;

CREATE TABLE public."Ronde" (

    "Id" serial,
    "Rondenummer" integer,
    "Woord" text,

) INHERITS (public."Spel");
```

Errormessage

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
> LINE 21: ) INHERITS (public."Spel");
>            ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 462
> ```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: I'm not an postgres expert but why do you use `"`? In the example there is no `"`

Comment: Because it's autogenerated in that way by postgres. I also tried somethings without " and that didn't work.

Comment: A redundant comma in `"Woord" text,`

Comment: Suggestion: don't use double-quotes in PostgreSQL, and if you use PGAdmin or some other GUI tool, don't use UPPER CASE anything in table/column identifiers. You will lead a happier life that way. Also, good eye @klin.

Comment: First of all: do not use double quotes if you do not want to separate table like "FooTable" and "footable". Just `create FooTable` and `select * from FooTable` if you want.

Comment: More background to what z4-tier suggested: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error might be a bug in PgAdmin4.  The quote marks are getting transferred in URI escaped form.  Or perhaps it is not a bug and you are somehow mis-using it.

The second error is because you have a trailing comma after the definition of the final column in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  SQL is not Perl or Python, you can't just add extraneous trailing commas and have them be ignored.